# Android released - doesn't support framework version

Tags: android, release, google-developers-console, android-min-sdk, targetsdkversion

This is my first release on Google play, so please bear with me, it might be a very simple question.
I have released a version of my app a few weeks ago with no problem for my tester.

Now on a new version, he's getting a message that his phone is not compatible with the app version, so he can't test it anymore. I don't think I made major changes on my app, just a few UI improvements and lowered the minSdk from 28 to 26 (I have tried to put it back to 28 and it didn't fix anything).

Google console says that my app **Doesn't support framework version (2,616 devices!) ***28 and onwards***** - but I though i did what should be done with "minSdkVersion 26".

Any help would be really appreciated!

Here's more info about my app :

Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' version '0.5'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyzthis.myapp.this"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.7"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'



    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

And here's my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xyzthis.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />


    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:name="xyzthis.myapp.ui.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_square"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_rounded"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme”
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <receiver
            android:name="xyzthis.myapp.ui.xlocation.MyBroadCastReceiver"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="xyzthis.myapp.ui.xlocation.AutoStartGeo"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="xyzthis.myapp.ui.xlocation.LocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />


        <service
            android:name="xyzthis.myapp.ui.xlocation.OnStartService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="xyzthis.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out? I am on the same boat. Mine says "doesn't support framework version: Between 21-31"